# Mapping instance variables type to template member function

Tags: c++, templates

Imagine I have

```
struct A {
 template <class T>
 T getFirstElement();

 vector<float> floatVector;
 vector<int> intVector;
};
```

in the implelemtation file:

```
template <>
float A::getFirstElement<float>() {
  return floatVector[0];
}

template <>
int A::getFirstElement<int>() {
  return intVector[0];
}
```

Since I know the types of my member variables, even naming them seems overkill. Is there a way to have something (like a typelist) that states at compile time what are the members for this structure? Would like to have something more concise and without explicit template specialization.

Comment: Why not making the whole class a template? Are you asking for a XY-problem?

Comment: no... it's about code reuse for accessing member variables

Answer (score 4):

With `std::tuple` you may do

```
struct A {
    template <class T>
    T getFirstElement() const
    {
        return std::get<std::vector<T>>(Vectors)[0];
    }

    std::tuple<std::vector<float>, std::vector<int>> Vectors;
};
```

And with variadic template:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct A_impl {
    template <class T>
    T getFirstElement() const
    {
        return std::get<std::vector<T>>(Vectors)[0];
    }

    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> Vectors;
};

struct A : A_impl<float, int> {};
```

Comment: I really like this. I thought that tuple could help, indeed

Comment: hmm doesn't work? no matching function for call to "get" in both solutions

Comment: "candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter"

Comment: @AlexDarsonik: `std::get<T>` requires c++14: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/257c8d67cdf0ece2). You may find implementation of `get<T>` for c++11 though.

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct VectorProvider
{
  std::vector<T> vector;

  auto& get() {
    return vector;
  }
};

struct A
  : VectorProvider<float>, VectorProvider<int> {

 template <typename T>
 T getFirstElement() {
   return VectorProvider<T>::get()[0];
 }
};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b64a0dda78c1aad)

Comment: I also like this, but I think that the solution of @jarod42 is cleaner... and doesn't use inheritance